# Running a Development Copy of WordPress?

Tags: localhost

- Download a copy of development site (in wordpress) + the database into my local machine
- I reconfigured site_url & home in database
- The url is myhost/wordpress
- htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

- I use permalink link: myhost/wordpress/%category%/%postname%/
- Issue: the admin end seems working, but the non of the urls are working. It gives me 404 error.

**Update:** I solved it by adding "AllowOverride All" to apache config. It was changed back to default after upgrade. The lesson for me is: I should look around myself, rather than go too far away from the problem.

Comment: Try changing every URL in database. Use can use find and replace.

Comment: Try deleting your current `.htaccess` and let WordPress create one for you when you save your permalinks structure. Changing "every url in the database" won't fix that problem IMHO.

Comment: I tried to delete .htaccess, but no luck. Same .htaccess is generated. I did a find and replace in db, but no luck. The hierarchy for me: localhost/parent-page-1/parent-page-2/the-actual-page, so the permalink is localhost/wordpress/%category%/%postname%/ (Is it correct?) If I permalink to http://localhost/wordpress/?p=123, this works, but is not I want

Answer (score 0):

You can open your database in a text editor and make a search and replace in the database. You have to change developmentsite.com for localsite.com. This method usually gives problems with theme options and widgets settings. To avoid these problems you can use the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicator/. This has given me excellent results.